# gulp task works when called manually, but throws errors when called by gulp.watch

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using [gulp](/questions/tagged/gulp)'s built-in method `gulp.watch` to spy on changes in my Javascript files.

This is the `buildJs` task definition:

```
gulp.task('buildJs', function() {
    var combined = combiner.obj([
        gulp.src([
            './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            './bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.js',
            './bower_components/lodash/lodash.min.js',
            paths.dev.js + '**/*.js'
        ]),
        sourcemaps.init(),
        concat('all.js'),
        sourcemaps.write('.'),
        rename('all.min.js'),
        gulp.dest(paths.pub.js)
    ]);

    combined.on('error', console.error.bind(console));
    return combined;
});
```

When I call the `gulp buildJs` manually, all works like a charm, no matter whether the file that is supposed to be created (`all.min.js`) already exists or not:

```
gulp buildJs
[16:21:40] Using gulpfile c:\src\portal\branches\octopus-working\Modules\gulpfile.js
[16:21:40] Starting 'buildJs'...
[16:21:40] Finished 'buildJs' after 124 ms

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I assign this task to a watcher, it seems it properly calls `buildJs` task, but this time with a different outcome:

```
gulp watchJs
[16:15:44] Using gulpfile c:\src\portal\branches\octopus-working\Modules\gulpfile.js
[16:15:44] Starting 'watchJs'...
[16:15:44] Finished 'watchJs' after 16 ms
[16:15:56] Starting 'buildJs'...
{ [Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'c:\src\portal\branches\octopus-working\Modules\Static\Portal\js\all.min.js']
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'c:\\src\\portal\\branches\\octopus-working\\Modules\\Static\\Portal\\js\\all.min.js' }
[16:15:56] 'buildJs' errored after 107 ms
[16:15:56] Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'c:\src\portal\branches\octopus-working\Modules\Static\Portal\js\all.min.js'
    at Error (native)
```

This is my watch definition:

```
gulp.task('watchJs', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.dev.js + '**/*.js', ['buildJs']);
});
```

And just for the sake of completeness, here's my `paths` object:

```
var paths = {
    dev: {
        scss: './assets/styles/',
        js: './assets/scripts/',
        html: './Templates/__DEV_static_html/'
    },
    pub: {
        css: './Static/Portal/css',
        js: './Static/Portal/js',
        html: './Static/Portal'
    }
};
```

So why does it work when called manually, but not when called by `gulp.watch`?

Comment: Where is gulpfile located? `c:\src\portal\branches\octopus-working\Modules\gulpfile.js ` ?

Comment: At `c:\src\portal\branches\octopus-working\Modules\gulpfile.js`.